# Delay de renderização com Angular + jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Algumas funções do jQuery ou diretivas do Angular, não são carregados ou renderizados no carregamento da página.

Em vários pontos do APP tive que aplicar o timeout para funcionar tudo normalmente.

Atualmente estou carregando o angular dessa forma, e logo abaixo carrego o jquery, foi a unica solução para que funcionasse, mesmo que com timeout:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);

        jQuery(function($){
            $(window).load(function(){
                if($("‪#‎selection‬").length)
                    $(".languages").show();
```

Qual a maneira correta para utilizar os dois ao mesmo tempo e renderizar tudo sem precisar de timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa é uma dúvida muito comum, o angular realmente renderiza elementos da página e diretiva sem ter carregado alguns elementos, isso é normal. Para corrigir isso, existe uma diretiva do próprio core do angular chamada ngCloak, você pode ver como usar aqui nas documentações:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

É necessário se atentar que você precisa incluir o css para sumir elementos com o atributo ngCloak conforme consta na especificação da diretiva.

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Já tinha visto, mas nem me lembrei dessa diretiva... valeu Ricardo, abraços